# Why Number([]) return 0 while Number({}) return NaN?

Tags: javascript

In my opinion, Number constructor will call `String([])` so `Number([])` equals to `Number("")`. So it returns 0. Also, Number constructor will call `String({})` so `Number({})` equals to `Number("[object Object]")`. So it returns NaN. But I'm no sure.

Comment: Yes, the number constructor will call `.toString()` on your objects (provided that `.valueOf()` doesn't return a primitive, which in your case it doesn't). Then it'll try and covert the primitive value to numbers, your logic is correct and you can follow the spec to see how it works: https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/numbers-and-dates.html#sec-number-constructor-number-value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you're right.

The Number constructor [will call `ToNumeric`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-number-constructor-number-value) on its argument, which then calls [ToNumber](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-tonumber) on it, which calls [ToPrimitive](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-toprimitive) on the object with a hint of number, which results in [OrdinaryToPrimitive](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ordinarytoprimitive) being called, which does

```
1. If hint is string, then
  a. Let methodNames be « "toString", "valueOf" ».
2. Else,
  a. Let methodNames be « "valueOf", "toString" ».
3. For each element name of methodNames, do
  a. Let method be ? Get(O, name).
  b. If IsCallable(method) is true, then
    i. Let result be ? Call(method, O).
    ii. If Type(result) is not Object, return result.
```

The hint is `number`, so the method names called are first `valueOf` and then (if that doesn't exist) `toString`.

`valueOf` returns the object itself in the case of a plain object, and the array itself in the case of an array, so that's no help - it moves on to `toString`.

`Array.prototype.toString` returns the array values joined - `arr.toString()` is equivalent to `arr.join(',')`. The empty array joins into the empty string. So

```
Number([])
```

turns into

```
Number('')
```

and so the empty string turns into 0.

But objects, when `toString` is called on them, give `[object Object]`

```js
console.log({}.toString());
```

which cannot be coerced into a number, thus NaN.

Comment: But how to figure out the hint? For `{} + 'abc'`, I think the hint should be a string, but what is called isn't String({}) but Number({}). And it finally return NaN. Wht here it processes the `{}` object like a number instead of a string?

Comment: When either side of a `+` is not a number, both sides are concatenated like strings. This is different from the Number function, which tries to turn its argument into a number instead.

Comment: But `{} + abc` isn't `"[object Object]abc"`

Comment: Yes it is. `console.log({} + 'abc')`

Comment: wait, I mean when I print `{}+abc` directly in the devtools instead of using `console.log`

Comment: The `{}` is interpreted as an empty block, and the `+` as unary `+`. You're not using the `+` binary operator.

Comment: Thanks. How about `{a:1} + 3`? Is `{a:1}` still an empty block?

Comment: No, it's a block, but the block is not empty. It has a label named `a` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label and an unused expression `1`.

Comment: Yes. But `{a:1} + 3` returns 3(not using console.log) even if `{a:1}` is not empty

Comment: Indeed - it's a block followed by an expression that uses unary plus. The console will print the final expression evaluated, generally. In that case, it's the `+3`. The `{a: 1}` block is a separate statement.